# In this code below, what do the parenthesis do? Or rather, what does this whole call ACTUALLY call?

Tags: salesforce

[SELECT i.Name,(SELECT Name FROM Line_items__r ORDER BY Name) FROM Invoice__c i
WHERE i.Name = :invoiceName LIMIT 1];

Why does there need to be an i variable and the parenthesis? For instance, why not just do:

SELECT Name FROM Invoice__c WHERE Name =: invoiceName LIMIT 1? Is the parenthesis like a way to just specifically get the line items?

A walk through of the code would be extremely helpful, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to execute them to see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

The following part is a sub query:

```
SELECT Name FROM Line_items__r ORDER BY Name
```

It is SOQL's way to traversing a parent-to-child relationship. See [Using Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm?search_text=subquery). As it is a child relationship, there could be multiple sub results returned. The parenthesis are required as part of the sub query syntax.

The `i` variable probably isn't strictly necessary. However, it helps to disambiguate the Name field of the `Invoice__c` record from the Name field of the `Line_items__c` records.